# Download the Facebook image in the background in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on Android project in which I need get the image from Facebook and show it on the UI. I am able to get the URL for the Facebook Image which I need to execute so that I can get the image.

Below is the URL which I need to execute to get my facebook image and that below URL I get from `userList.get(position).getPhoto()`.

`http://graph.facebook.com/fb-user-id/picture`

Below is the code which I am using to get the Image in the Background but somehow my background task is not getting called and Facebook image is not getting shown on my UI.

And there is no error as well.

Is there any better way to do this to get the image and show it on UI?

```
/**
 * Depending on the gender, set the image properly for the users
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View vi = convertView;

if (convertView == null) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
}
TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
TextView text1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
ImageView genderImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image1);
text.setText("" + userList.get(position).getFirstName() + " "
    + userList.get(position).getLastName());
text1.setText("" + userList.get(position).getDistance() + " meter");

if (userList.get(position).getGender() == 1) {
    genderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_sign);
} else {
    genderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_sign);
}

//Calling background task to get the image but somehow, it's not working
new DownloadImageTask(image).execute(userList.get(position).getPhoto());

return vi;
}
```

Below is the class which will get the Image in Background and then show it on UI.

```
/**
     * A simple class to do the task in background so that it can download the image without blocking the main thread
     * 
     */
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    }
```

Comment: are u getting any error at runtime? because new `DownloadImageTask(image).execute(userList.get(position).getPhoto());` line executed every time when view's added to ListView row. so you will need to check if `DownloadImageTask` is running or not before starting next task or use Handler instead of AsyncTask in which you can queue all requests and process one y one. you can also try it using [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I am not getting any error at runtime. Can you provide any simple example to do this with the code I have for the Facebook image URL.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you try to make the *(ImageView)image* a Global Variable ?

Not need to send it in the DownloadImageTask, just

```
image.setImageBitmap(result);
```

In my code, I set it inside **onProgressUpdate**